# How to hide a popover when clicking anywhere?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this popover and to show it, i click on the icon. To hide it, the same thing. How do i close it when i click anywhere else on the page? 
Code:

```
<span uib-popover-template="'app/components/popover/popover.template.html'" popover-placement="right"
              popover-trigger="outsideClick"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></span>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you accept an answer (green mark left side of the answer) it is solved your issue? :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of AngularUI's popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover):

> The `outsideClick` trigger will cause the popover to toggle on click,
>   and hide when anything else is clicked.

**[JSFiddle demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/1tnc24ry/)**

Comment: Which version of AngularUI are you using? `outsideClick` is available only since 1.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).click(function() {
//Hide the pop if visible
});

//stop propagation of document body
$('#pop').click(function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
angular
    .module('modulename')
    .factory('clickAnywhereButHereService', function($document){
      var tracker = [];

      return function($scope, expr) {
        var i, t, len;
        for(i = 0, len = tracker.length; i < len; i++) {
          t = tracker[i];
          if(t.expr === expr && t.scope === $scope) {
            return t;    
          }
        }
        var handler = function() {
          $scope.$apply(expr);
        };

        $document.on('click', handler);

        // IMPORTANT! Tear down this event handler when the scope is destroyed.
        $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
          $document.off('click', handler);
        });

        t = { scope: $scope, expr: expr };
        tracker.push(t);
        return t;
      };
    });

     angular
    .module('modulename')
    .directive('clickAnywhereButHere', function($document, clickAnywhereButHereService){
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
          var handler = function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
          };
          elem.on('click', handler);

          scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
            elem.off('click', handler);
          });

          clickAnywhereButHereService(scope, attr.clickAnywhereButHere);
        }
      };
    });`
```

This will work. use this directive on `span`.